# IE8/9 + Quirks mode opacity not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I'm developing on quirks mode (argh...), and added opacity on some icons (no opacity when hovered), but it will not work in IE8/9 + Quirks.

```
    .icons {
      display: inline;
      height: auto !important;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 1%;
      position:relative;
      zoom: 1;
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=50);
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .icons:hover {
      zoom: 1;
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/C3atq/

JSFiddle looks terrible in Quirks mode so it's a bit hard to show this...
I read somewhere that IE9 opacity doesn't work without a width/height on the element, my height is % based and don't have a width because I am using media queries

Comment: I'm pretty sure `-ms-filter` works in quirks mode...

Comment: Just wondering, why do you even need to support quirks mode?

Comment: I just tested http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html (fitting site name) in IE8 Quirks (IE8 with Browser Mode: IE8; Document Mode: Quirks), and the filter test paragraph on that page is transparent.

Comment: @jdwire Developing on top of a corporate application that only works in/enforces Quirks mode. Wouldn't if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure exactly what the problem is, but I resolved it with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.icons img').css('opacity', '0.6');
    $('div.icons img').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('opacity', '1.0');
        $('div.icons img').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.6');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess you can always count on jQuery even in the midst of corporate pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I also have to support quirks mode and *without* JQuery, but for me, I needed to use "display: inline-block" as opposed to just "display: inline".

The following worked for me:

"display: inline-block; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50);";

Comment: +1. This is the answer that worked for me. Didn't want to have to introduce a jQuery function for something that we should be able to do in CSS